# Updating static source based on Kafka Stream using Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, kafka-consumer-api, spark-structured-streaming

I am using spark-sql 2.4.1v with java8.

I have a scenario where I have some meta data in dataset1 i.e. which is loaded from an HDFS Parquet file.

And I have another dataset2 which is read from a Kafka Stream.

```
For each record from dataset2 for column1 I need to check  columnX in dataset2 
if its there in dataset1. 

If it is there in dataset1,then I need replace the columnX value with column1 value  of dataset1 
Else
  I need to add increment (max(column1 ) from dataset1 ) by one and store it dataset1.
```

Some sample data you can see here:

https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/1165111237342523/3447405230020171/7035720262824085/latest.html

How this can be done in sSpark?

Example:

```
val df1 = Seq(
  ("20359045","2263"),
("8476349","3280"),
("60886923","2860"),  
("204831453","50330"),
("6487533","48236"),
("583633","46067"),  
  ).toDF("company_id_external","company_id")

 val df2 = Seq(
  ("60886923","Chengdu Fuma Food Co,.Ltd"), //company_id_external match found in df1 
("608815923","Australia Deloraine Dairy Pty Ltd ),
("59322769","Consalac B.V.")
("583633","Boso oil and fat Co., Ltd.      ") //company_id_external match found in df1
  )toDF("company_id_external","companyName")
```

**If match found in df1**

```
Here only two records of df1 "company_id_external" matching to df2 "company_id_external"
    i.e. 60886923 & 583633  ( first and last record)

    For these records of df2  
    i.e. ("60886923","Chengdu Fuma Food Co,.Ltd")  becomes ==> ("2860","Chengdu Fuma Food Co,.Ltd")
          ("583633","Boso oil and fat Co., Ltd.      ")  becomes ==>  ("46067","Boso oil and fat Co., Ltd.      ")
```

**Else match not found in df1**

For other two of df2 there is no "company_id_external" match in df1, need to generate it company_id and add to df1
 i.e. ("608815923","Australia Deloraine Dairy Pty Ltd ),
       ("59322769","Consalac B.V.")

company_id generation logic
 new company_id = max(company_id) of df1 + 1 
 From the above max is 50330  + 1  => 50331    add this record to df1 i.e. ("608815923","50331")
 Do the same for other one i.e.  add this record to df1 i.e. ("583633","50332")

```
 **So now** 

df1 = Seq(
        ("20359045","2263"),
        ("8476349","3280"),
        ("60886923","2860"),  
        ("204831453","50330"),
        ("6487533","48236"),
        ("583633","46067"), 
        ("608815923","50331")
        ("583633","50332")
          ).toDF("company_id_external","company_id")
```

Comment: Will do later tonight

Comment: @thebluephantom thank you so much for your quick response.

Comment: Streaming or Structured Streaming? I am not a Java expert BTW, so I can only offer general advice. How big are the batches? How big are the parquet files? Do you cache this, can it be updated? I assume the metadata is a small file that can be cached? Not sure I get this aspect: For each record from dataset2 for column1 I need to check columnX in dataset2 if its there in dataset2.The CoulmnX and columns 1 refer to dataset2...

Comment: @thebluephantom  Structured Streaming , not a problem you provide advice in scala i can convert into java.  Yes I cache this as it is small files ..It should be updated else I cant reflect the newly added record. How to refresh cache/loaded parquet file again with newly added record/s ? If you see the databricks link i provided you would come to know it.  In short , if column1 of dataframe1  value in columnX value of dataframe2 , then I need then I need to replace column1 value of dataframe1. Else add column1 value of dataframe1 to dataframe2 as a new record. Let me know if u need more info

Comment: @thebluephantom I added "Example :" section in the question , can you have a look plz.

Comment: so hdfs is in general immutable. ok I will look later.

Comment: Check Foreach statement if correct

Comment: @thebluephantom yes true

Comment: @thebluephantom where is foreach here ?

Comment: for each record in grey box, is the statement correct?

Comment: @thebluephantom yes they are all statements only i.e. use-case description ... is the use-case understandable ? or any more clarity or info needed ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197907/discussion-between-bdlearner-and-thebluephantom).

Comment: @bartosz25  can you please send your edits to approve , accidentally i rejected it sorry

Comment: so how many companies? not really that maybut not a realistic scenario. look at my best received answer, it will give you guidance in scala. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058951/how-to-implement-slowly-changing-dimensions-scd2-type-2-in-spark/54066697#54066697

Comment: presume you want to write the data? No need for parquet.

Comment: small files problem as well.